# Pythonic way to replace specific values with other values of numpy array within particular indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have seen answers for each part of my question. For example `np.where(arr, b, c)` converts all b's in arr to c. Or `arr[arr == b] = c` does the same. However, I have 1000 labels in a numpy array, `labels_test`, including 1 and 6. I want to flip 30 percent of the correct labels to wrong ones to make an erroneous dataset. So I create the following list of indices that should be changed.

```
l = [np.random.choice(1000) for x in range(100)] (I am not sure if each index is repeated once)
```

I want something like

```
np.put(labels_test, l, if labels_test[l] ==1, then 6 and  if labels_test[l] ==6, then 1`
```

We can do it for the following toy example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
labels_test = [np.random.choice([1,6]) for x in range(20)]
[6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> labels_test = np.random.choice([1, 6], 20)
>>> ind = np.random.choice(labels_test.shape[0], labels_test.shape[0]//3, replace=False)
>>> labels_test
array([1, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1])
>>> labels_test[ind] = 7 - labels_test[ind]
>>> labels_test
array([1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6])
```

This flips exactly 30% (rounded down to the nearest integer) by sampling without replacement.  Depending on your requirements, a suitable alternative might be to select every label with probability 0.3.

Comment: Isn't there any general way to do that. I mean if we have more labels (0,1,2,...,9) and want to do that for all of them or eve the percentage changes.